# Entered USA with esta, leaving to Canada for 2 days and come back

Tags: usa, canada, esta

I am visiting my brother here in the US, and I am staying for 3 weeks. I used esta in order to come to the US. We want to visit Montreal (Canada) for two days and come back to the US. (We are going there by car)

Will I have problem coming back to the US? I mean esta doesn't expire for at least 2 more months, but if I leave the states, and come back two days later, would esta still be valid? can I come back? Thanks!

Comment: As long as you understand that your trip to Canada doesn't reset your 90 days and you still have some time left over on the 90 day count you should not have a problem.

Comment: He's not asking about a 90 day limit, he just wants to know if it's possible to return.

Comment: @MarkMayo 21 days in the US + 69 days in Canada...

Comment: Yes, but you will not get a new admission stamp. You will have to leave on or before the date on your existing WT stamp.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, your ESTA is valid for up to two years, and you can spend up to 90 days at a time in the country.  However, it's still up to the immigration officer to determine (at any time) whether or not you should be allowed back in to the country.  So problems - not because of your ESTA, I did what you're describing back in July (went from the US (1 week) to Cuba, Canada and then back into the US 2 weeks later), and had no issues.  A week later I returned to Canada for 2 days, and then went back to Seattle to fly out. So basically what you're describing!

Of course, they may have the usual questions about your departure flights, accommodation etc that you might get on your first arrival too, but as long as you have those sorted, you should be fine.